# Halton set in MATLAB around a pre-specified point

Tags: matlab

I want to generate a Halton set of 4D points in MATLAB around a pre-specified point `a=(-1,2,3,0)`. I found several explanations on how to generate an Halton set of 4D points in MATLAB, for example, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236269/change-the-random-number-generator-in-matlab-function), we can do

```
p = haltonset(4,'Skip',1e2,'Leap',1e1);
p = scramble(p,'RR2');
```

What confuses me is  the instruction *around a pre-specified point* `a=(-1,2,3,0)`. What does it mean exactly and how can I implement it in MATLAB?

My understanding is that `haltonset` gives points in `[0,1]^4`. Therefore, the "centre" of these points is `[1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2]`. Thus, I could try to "recentre" them around `a` by first selecting `10^6` points from `p` by doing `p_sel=p(1:10^6,:)`, then recentring them by doing `shift_dim=a-1/2, p_recentered=p_sel+shift_dim`.

Comment: This might be more of a mathematical question than a MATLAB one. It reads to me that if you understand how to define a Halton set around another point than the origin, it'd be easy to implement yourself. You might want to try [math.se] for this.

Comment: What is bad with the shifting strategy? I would have done it this way...